# What is this type of clamp called?

Tags: part-identification

This is a flat, C-shaped metal piece with a singular hole at the bottom through which a grub screw assures that the heated bed and the glass plate are kept tightly together.

Looking for clamps, I've not found this one. I can get close through "glass clamp", but all of them have two screws.

Both plates together are about 9 mm in thickness.

[image: Photo of the bed clip/clamp on a 3D printer]

Answer (score 2):

These will commonly go by the term "bed clip". The problem with doing a search with those terms will not get the result you are looking for. Doing a search with the terms "[3D printing bed clip](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+printer+glass+bed+clip&newwindow=1&sca_esv=559732191&sxsrf=AB5stBgfXjdHra-xglysRj4DG1XT2fLcpg%3A1692889361087&ei=EXHnZPWABeG7qtsPwt2qmAM&oq=3d+bed+clip&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiCzNkIGJlZCBjbGlwKgIIATIFEAAYgAQyBhAAGAcYHjIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgIGB4yChAAGAgYHhgPGAoyCBAAGIoFGIYDSOksUKUSWOIXcAF4AZABAJgBdqABsQKqAQMyLjG4AQHIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgIKEAAYigUYsAMYQ8ICBxAAGA0YgATCAggQABgIGB4YDcICDBAAGAgYHhgNGA8YCuIDBBgAIEGIBgGQBgo&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)" will get you what you are looking for.

There are different types and styles, so you will have to search for the particular one that you want.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not it. I've searched through the search results and none of them resemble the one in the picture.

Comment: They don't have to be the exact same. Their purpose is to hold the glass bed to the carriage, not to mention they are adjustable.